# Convert a string to XML input stream in java

Tags: java, apache-fop

I'm trying to generate a PDF document using FOP and Java.

I receive the XML as a string and not as a file.

How can I convert this XML string to an XML input stream so that I can call xslfoTransformer.transform(source, res); where source is my XML string as an Input stream.

Please provide your suggestions.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You probably want to convert it to a `Reader`, not an `InputStream`. Use [StringReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) to do this. StreamSource has a constructor that takes a Reader, and you can pass that `StreamSource` to Transformer.transform().

I say you probably want a `Reader` rather than an `InputStream` because a String holds characters, not bytes, and an `InputStream` is a stream of bytes while a `Reader` is a stream of characters.

Comment: I tried this method but I'm getting an exception.
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.fop.area.AreaTreeHandler.endDocument(AreaTreeHandler.java:264)
 at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder.endDocument(FOTreeBuilder.java:171)
 at net.sf.saxon.event.ContentHandlerProxy.close(ContentHandlerProxy.java:255)
 at net.sf.saxon.event.ImplicitResultChecker.close(ImplicitResultChecker.java:69)
 at net.sf.saxon.event.ProxyReceiver.close(ProxyReceiver.java:87)
 at net.sf.saxon.event.ComplexContentOutputter.close(ComplexContentOutputter.java:468)
 at 

Any clues?

Comment: Ok..I figured it out...

It worked when I renamed the root element of the xml to 'root'.

Thanks for the help!!!!

Answer (score 54):

```
new StreamSource(new StringReader(str))
```

Comment: Note: `new StreamSource(str)` won't work because it expects `str` to be a URL

Answer (score 2):

Use [ByteArrayInputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html):

```
String S = ...;
InputStream source = new ByteArrayInputStream(S.getBytes(encoding))
```

Comment: Implies you know the encoding of the XML. Which is normally not true.